# Why is my chrome extension able to import a script which is not mentioned in its content_security_policy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have a chrome extension. The manifest.json(v2) has :

`"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js ;"`

Its main.css imports the google-sans font:

`@import url("http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/google-sans");`

Why is this working? Shouldn't the browser stop the code from getting any code/scripts from a site not mentioned in the content_security_policy?

Comment: It works probably because the CSS is considered same-origin due to `access-control-allow-origin: *` header in the response.

Comment: I am also doing a `<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/insert-row-above.png" />`. This site is neither mentioned in the `permissions` nor in the `csp`. Why is it still loading the image?

Comment: It's the same reason: the server sets `access-control-allow-origin: *`.

Answer (score 0):

The CSP is not supposed to contain the path to individual files, instead, you should only include the domains, like:

```
default-src 'self'; 
script-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net;
```

So I guess the browser ignored it because it was not valid? do also check the policy errors in the browser F12 console.

Comment: Unable to find any policy errors in the Applications tab. This is an extension which works on top of a site. I can't find a way to look for things related to the extension only and not the site itself. Also, even If I make the change to script-src, still it is loading css/images, etc from other pages. Any way to confirm if the csp is working or not?

`default-src 'self'; ` - Even with this as my csp, everything still works

Comment: Browser extensions has the full power to remove or alter CSP's , so probably it removes the CSP before the browser actually receives the final response headers. Perhaps look in the developer tools -> network to see if the header is actually there? Otherwise, remove the extensions? they usually just makes your browser more insecure